# Which type of data can be stored in Agens Graph (Graph database)?

Tags: postgresql, graph-databases, agens-graph

I read the documentation about Agens Graph.
Your graph database is based on PostgreSQL, right?
So I think your solution is operating anywhere including general RDBMS features.

Then I have a question for data type.
How can be stored in Agens Graph?
The rules are following RDBMS or something special way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agens Graph is a graph database based-on PostgreSQL. So every feature in PostgreSQL is available in Agens Graph too, including data types. You can use any data types available in PostgreSQL.
Agens Graph has two additional data types, vertex and edge. User can manipulate in terms of vertex and edge. Of course, this is a basic feature of the graph database. And because Agens graph supports the property graph data model, so vertexes and edges can have arbitrary properties. Agens Graph store properties using JSON format (more specifically stored in JSONB type of PostgreSQL). One can store any JSON documents as vertexes' or edges' property. And you can also store data from PostgreSQL's datatype. Then the data is converted to internal representation of PostgreSQL and stored in JSON format. You can index the property value using the expression index and you can also exploit a variety of PostgreSQL indexes including Btree, BRIN, GIST, GIN, etc.

Comment: That sounds interesting. Is that also available as an extension? Or only as a modified Postgres?

Comment: Agens Graph is a forked project of PostgreSQL and it is not an extension of PostgreSQL. Thank you.

Comment: Here after quite some years, and surely  things have changed. To me it seems that at least dates (a.k.a timestamps) are not directly supported as _property type_ since I'm not totally confident that I can query them like real dates (see [the issue I opened on GitHub](https://github.com/bitnine-oss/agensgraph/issues/528)) - may that be because I didn't define a specific index on the property?